Error while anchor build: `solana-program v2.0.4` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.75.0
I am trying to build a project from the solana courses.
The anchor.toml is the following:
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.30.1"
anchor-spl = "0.30.1"
solana-program = "=1.18.1"
this is the error i get:
cargo update -p solana-program@2.0.4 --precise ver

After 'this is the error I get' - please add the error!

You might need to upgrade your Solana CLI suite.
The recommended version with anchor 0.30.1 is
1.18.17
solana-install init 1.18.17

ref: https://www.anchor-lang.com/release-notes/0.30.1
